# Very complex Cross Tab dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am relatively a new to sql development. I want a dynamic cross tab query. Let me explain my tables first. I have a table SalesOrder. Each SalesOrder has SalesItems. Each item has productID and each product has fabricID. Each SalesItem has a field lengthDelivered. 
Further more, each salesOrder has a ClienTID

Now i want a query which will list all fabricNames in columns. it means that all fabric names are column headers in my case. In row header, all clients will be displayed. Against every client, every fabric will have a value that will indicate how much length against this fabric is sold to this client. Please help me soon. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you post the actual table definitions?  `CREATE TABLE` statements would be great.  See my answer for how to generically do a dynamic pivot in SQL Server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a procedure to do this a while back.  Feel free to use it -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE do_pivot
    @table sysname,                     -- Name of the table with source data to pivot
    @column_field sysname,              -- Field used to generate new columns
    @value_field sysname = '',          -- Values to group within new columns
    @order_by sysname = NULL,           -- Optional order by field
    @function sysname = MAX,            -- Optional function to perform on values
    @reverse_columns bit = 0           -- If set to 1, reverses order of pivoted columns
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @pivot_fields nvarchar(max);

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
        -- Get unique values
        set @pivot_fields_OUT = (
            select distinct ''['' + CAST(' + @column_field + ' as nvarchar(max)) + ''],''
            from ' + @table + '
            order by 1 ' + case
                when @reverse_columns = 0 then 'asc' else 'desc'
            end + '
            for xml path('''')
        );
        -- Remove last comma
        set @pivot_fields_OUT = LEFT(@pivot_fields_OUT, LEN(@pivot_fields_OUT) - 1);
    ';

    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@pivot_fields_OUT nvarchar(max) OUTPUT',
                       @pivot_fields_OUT=@pivot_fields OUTPUT;

    set @sql = N'
        select *
        from ' + @table + '
        pivot (
            ' + @function + '(' + @value_field + ')
            for ' + @column_field + ' in (' + @pivot_fields + ')
        ) as pvt ' + case
            when @order_by is null then ''
            else 'order by ' + @order_by
        end;

    exec(@sql);

END
```